# Should I start with Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I have just started my quantum mechanics course for school (homeschool), and I was using No-Nonsense Quantum Mechanics by Jakob Schwichtenberg, I have since discovered that the book sucks. I have now narrowed down my textbook search to Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics and Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics. But, I have heard that Shankar is better than Griffiths and more in depth mathematically. I already know Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics, linear algebra, calculus 1-3, (a good bit of) complex analysis, and some basic group theory. Would this be good enough to start Shankar? Or should I just do Griffiths instead?

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: You could try rephrasing this question using more objective wording. For example, ask about the relative strengths and weakness of Griffiths versus Shankar for beginners doing self-study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the standard. Modern Quantum Mechanics by J.J Sakurai. Especially since you're already familiar with the prerequisites.

Comment: Quantum Mechanics Concepts and Applications by Nouredine Zettilli is a good alternative too.

Comment: I'll check them both out.